# changes in recorded high fps video files from iOS 8.0.2 to 8.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-processing, frame-rate, ios8.1

My app works with 240 fps video from the iPhone 6/Plus camera, combining multiple overlaid AVMutableCompositionTracks into one composition for export. Both viewing in the app and exporting can take place either rendered out to 30 fps or at original fps.

For videos taken on 8.0.2 or before there is no issue whatsoever exporting at original fps and basically preserving all characteristics of the original file (except for the overlay). For videos taken on 8.1 there is about a 50% chance that the composition gets corrupted and fails to export, or when played back in-app freezes about a second into playback (while audio keeps playing for a while) before finally stopping with AVFoundationErrorCode -11819, "AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset".

If frameDuration is instead set to 1/30, 1/60, even 1/200 or sometimes up to around 1/220 for a 240 (well 239.84...) fps file, there is no issue with playback or export. Export also seems a bit more tolerant- than playback and sometimes goes through even when playback fails.

I have noticed changes in other apps with 8.1, MoviePro for example now records at around 207-209 fps when set to 240 fps and sometimes 59 when set to 60, while Apple's SloPoke example is more variable as well, usually recording at various values between 235-236. Apple's Camera app is still at 239.84 though.

Does anyone know what has changed and how to get around it? Obviously something about fps variability but how do I handle it? Or could it simply be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in AVPlayer and AVExportSession. Exports with no issue using AVAssetWriter.

Apple's newly updated sample project AVCustomEdit that uses a custom OpenGL compositor for transitions between clips demonstrates the same issue when modified to take an iOS 8.1 240 fps video and play it back at framerates near 240.

Can't believe I spent like 30 hours trying to figure out what was wrong when sidestepping it was this easy.

Comment: Make sure you get an Inspector report filed. Sounds like a nasty bug.

Answer (score 1):

*I have noticed changes in other apps with 8.1, MoviePro for example now records at around 207-209 fps when set to 240 fps*

This is a bug in MoviePro app that is fixed in upcoming update still to be submitted. On iOS 8.1, the new update pending submission records very close to 240 fps at all bit rates.